# Is the decorator pattern the correct pattern to be used on this situation

Tags: oop, design-patterns, decorator

I would like to ask if the decorator pattern suits my needs and is another way to make my software design much better?

Previously I have a device which is always on all the time. On the code below, that is the Device class. Now, to conserve some battery life, I need to turn it off then On again. I created a DeviceWithOnOffDecorator class. I used decorator pattern which I think helped a lot in avoiding modifications on the Device class. But having On and Off on every operation, I feel that the code doesn't conform to DRY principle.

```
namespace Decorator
{
    interface IDevice
    {
        byte[] GetData();
        void SendData();
    }


    class Device : IDevice
    {
        public byte[] GetData() {return new byte[] {1,2,3 }; }
        public void SendData() {Console.WriteLine("Sending Data"); }
    }


    // new requirement, the device needs to be turned on and turned off
    // after each operation to save some Battery Power
    class DeviceWithOnOffDecorator:IDevice
    {
        IDevice mIdevice;

        public DeviceWithOnOffDecorator(IDevice d)
        {
            this.mIdevice = d;
            Off();
        }

        void Off() { Console.WriteLine("Off");}
        void On() { Console.WriteLine("On"); }

        public byte[] GetData()
        {
            On();
            var b = mIdevice.GetData();
            Off();
            return b;
        }


        public void SendData()
        {
            On();
            mIdevice.SendData();
            Off();
        }
    }


    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Device device = new Device();
            DeviceWithOnOffDecorator devicewithOnOff = new DeviceWithOnOffDecorator(device);
            IDevice iDevice = devicewithOnOff;

            var data = iDevice.GetData();
            iDevice.SendData();
        }
    }
}
```

On this example: I just have two operations only **GetData** and **SendData**, but on the actual software there are lots of operations involved and I need to do enclose each operations with On and Off,

```
void AnotherOperation1()
{
On();
// do all stuffs here
Off();
}

byte AnotherOperation2()
{
On();
byte b;
// do all stuffs here
Off();
return b;
}
```

I feel that enclosing each function with On and Off is repetitive and is there a way to improve this?

Edit: Also, the original code is in C++. I just wrote it in C# here to be able to show the problem clearer.

Comment: Hmm.  What you're looking for would be a way to automate delegation to the methods of the `Device` class between your calls to `On()` and `Off()`.  Unfortunately, Java doesn't allow you to dynamically add methods, so you can't build the decorated version "on the fly".  If you care to dig into the bowels of the VM, it could possibly be done with a custom class-loader...but that's not a practical solution.  Instead, you might want to look at aspect-oriented programming.  A brief search shows there's some support for AspectJ with Android.  Conceptually, aspects let you 'hook' classes' methods.

Comment: hi thanks for the comment. However, I forgot to mention, that I am implementing this in C++. I just used C# in this case to be able to show the problem in a much clearer fashion.

Comment: Well, there's always AspectC++, or you could parse the `Device` class header and generate code for the decorated subclass (delegating the calls to the version from `Device` between `On()` and `Off()`), or you could just bite the bullet and add a generic "hook" interface to each method on `Device`.  Then your On/Off subclass could install hooks for powering on and off.  At least then the hooks in Device are generic (not coupled to the on/off feature)

Answer (score 0):

`Decorator` won't suite this purpose, since you are not adding the responsibility dynamically. To me what you need to do is intercept the request and execute `on()` and `off()` methods before and after the actual invocation. For that purpose write a `Proxy` that wraps the underlying instance and do the interception there while leaving your original type as it is.